# Не могу сделать HTML с AMP страницами копию сайта с XAMPP - совпадает имя папки и файла

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, xampp, amp

Приветствую!
Решил опробовать что такое AMP страницы, на WordPress сайте, который работает в XAMPP. Я генерю плагином Simply Static локальную копию сайта и заливаю на хостинг. И я решил на нём опробовать зверя "ускоренные страницы AMP" Поставил плагин AMP, который генерирует страницы с приставкой **/amp/**.
 Т.е. обычная страница http:\site.ru\samplename.html и её AMP страница http:\site.ru\samplename.html\amp\ Но я не могу сделать локальную копию: плагин создаёт локальную копию страницы, к примеру, http:\site.ru\samplename.html а папку **samplename.html** создать уже не может (пишет Unable to create temporary directory).

Что посоветуете? Может в htaccess как то сделать редирект, чтобы корневые html сохранялись в поддиректорию как то?

Comment: Не стоит лишать себя и пользователей всех возможностей и гибкости WordPress, превращая его в голую статику. Поставьте WP Super Cache и у вас будет то же самое - все страницы будут отдаваться в html, но при этом при обновлении страниц кеш html будет обновляться автоматически. И от косяков с Simply Static уйдете. Вот на тестовом сайте я сейчас включил WP Super Cache и AMP вместе. Посмотрите код страницы http://test.kagg.eu/at-commodi-quia-enim/amp/ через ctrl+U, увидите внизу, что это кеш, сгенерированный через WP Super Cache

Comment: Посмотрел WP Super Cache, да, там сделали умнее. Статьи как папки, а в них уже amp страницы.

Comment: Так это выглядит на сервере: http://take.ms/O0iGg